# how to output message from oracle trigger logon on database

Tags: oracle, triggers, output

Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_LOGON_TRIGG
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE 
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('Hello, ' || USER || '. Now is ' || SYSDATE );
END;
```

compiled successful.
But after logon nothing displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You better use a logging table to record the logon information.`dbms_output`  for a trigger is not reliable

Comment: My idea was to include `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` into the **(g)login.sql** file. However, it appears that user *first* gets connected, and settings from (g)login.sql are executed afterwards. So - no luck, as far as I can tell. But really, what would be that trigger's purpose? Imagine you log on through your Forms or Apex application - nobody would ever see that *output*.

Answer (score 0):

There are three parts to DBMS_OUTPUT. Firstly, it needs to be enabled so that the 'put' data gets recorded. You can do this in your trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_LOGON_TRIGG
AFTER LOGON ON schema
BEGIN
     dbms_output.enable;
     dbms_output.put_line('Hello, ' || USER || '. Now is ' || SYSDATE );
END;
/
```

The second part is the 'put'. The third part is the 'get'. The client (eg SQL*Plus) executes a GET / GET_LINES behind the scenes to fetch the data over to the client. It can then push those values to whatever output it is using.

If you have the enable and put in the trigger the data will be in the dbms_output buffer. After the SET SERVEROUTPUT ON in SQL*Plus, the next database operation should be followed by a fetch of the dbms_output buffer. It should be seen, but it may not occur quite where you expect. Try following the SET SERVEROUTPUT ON with an EXEC NULL as a dummy database operation.

===============================================================
Edit to add demo:

```
>CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_LOGON_TRIGG
  2  AFTER LOGON ON schema
  3  BEGIN
  4       dbms_output.enable;
  5       dbms_output.put_line('Hello, ' || USER || '. Now is ' || SYSDATE );
  6  END;
  7  /

Trigger created.

>conn ####
Enter password:
Connected.
>exec null
Hello, ####. Now is 05-MAR-18

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advice. But the compiler does not agree with you.

Comment: Works for me in 12.1. Older databases may differ slightly. Note: I went for a schema trigger rather than database one for my test.